# How to search data between two dates with timestamp in sap hana DB

Tags: sql, hana

**Query**

```
SELECT  * FROM "DD"."kidos.dd.data::DD_RECEIVE_NOTIFICATION_TBL" 
WHERE RECEIVED_DATE between 
DATE("2017-11-28T04:41:00.000Z") and DATE("2017-12-01T04:42:00.000Z");
```

I have two dates with timestamp. I have to search the data between two dates. In hana `DB` I initailized `"RECEIVED_DATE"` with `TIMESTAMP`. How to filter data's with in two date times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  * FROM "DD"."kidos.dd.data::DD_RECEIVE_NOTIFICATION_TBL"  WHERE RECEIVED_DATE between '2017-11-30T01:10:00.000Z' and '2017-12-01T23:42:00.000Z'
```